# How do I execute backend code from an extended django template?

Tags: google-app-engine, django-templates

I have a template page, `base.html` that has

```
{% if admin %}
  {% include "admin-page.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Now what I'd like to do is when `admin-page.html` is included (like above) I'd like to run some backend code that `admin-page.html` relies upon.

Typically when I want to call my backend I edit `urls.py` and tell it where to look, but since I'm never actually hitting the url `admin-page.html` I'm not sure how to talk to my python backend.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a custom template tag is what I was looking for.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 0):

How about in the admin-page.html itself you include the data you need by having in that page a separate mechanism to go and get and then display the data?

E.G. in your admin-page.html you have an AJAX component that upon loading in the browser retrieves the relevant information directly from your back end and displays it.

Same difference really as triggering it when the page is requested. And as you intended to include it in your initial display of that page presumably it returns the required data quite quickly, within the request limit.